# I want to import an .xls file into an Access database

Tags: import-from-excel

I want to import the data from several xls files into an Access database. Each xls file contains multiple worksheets, and there are 4 different types of tables. While importing, I can select the worksheets one by one. Is it possible to import these worksheets collectively? Also, how can I ensure that the transferred file format remains intact without any corruption during the transfer?

Any help is appreaciated, thanks

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

"I imported a file from Excel to Access. However, I couldn't obtain the desired data."